# If $K$ is compact then there is a compact $H$ with $d(K,\partial H)>0$

Tags: general-topology

I have questions about the following proposition and its proof.

> **Proposition:** Let $X$ be a locally compact and connected metric space and $K\subsetneq X$ a compact subset. Then there is a compact $H\subseteq X$ such that $K\subseteq int(H)$ and $d(K,\partial H)>0$.
>
> **Proof:** For every $x\in K$ let $U_x$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ with compact closure. Then $K$ is contained in a finite subcover $U_{x_1},...,U_{x_n}$ because $K$ is compact. Since $X$ is connected it contains no proper clopen subsets. This implies that
>
> $$K\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^nU_{x_j}\subsetneq\bigcup_{j=1}^n\overline{U_{x_j}}=:H.$$
>
> Then $H$ is compact and $K\subseteq int(H)$ and $K\cap\partial H=\emptyset$, thus $d(K,\partial H)>0$.

1) The proof says that since $X$ is connected the open subset $\bigcup_{j=1}^nU_{x_j}$ can't be equal to its closure... unless it is the whole $X$, I think. In that case $X$ would be compact and $H=X$. Which also implies $\partial H=\emptyset$. Can we still consider $d(K,\emptyset)$? Perhaps we just take it as $+\infty$?

2) I don't understand why it is important that $K\subsetneq H$. If $K=H$ then again $H$ is clopen, so $\partial H=\emptyset$. If we just consider $d(K,\emptyset)=+\infty >0$ then we don't even need $X$ to be connected. 
What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $d(A,\varnothing) = +\infty$ is a common convention. It's natural, because $\inf \varnothing = +\infty$. And yes, $K = H$ if $K$ happens to be open isn't a problem usually. There may be situations in which one needs $K \subsetneq H \subsetneq X$, but off the top of my head, I can't think of one.

Comment: Do you mean $K\subsetneq X$ in 2.)?

Comment: No. The proof of the proposition states that since $X$ is connected then $K\subsetneq H$ (unless $H=X$). And that's all why $X$ connected is needed. But I think this is wrong (because case $H=X$) and is not neccesary because we don't really need $K\neq H$ (as Daniel seems to agree too). @SeverinSchraven

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but when you have $H=K\subsetneq X$, then $\partial H= \partial K \neq \emptyset$. Because if $K$ was open, it would be all of $X$ which is not the case by assumption.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. My bad. Still let me put it in another words. If $X$ is not connected, the "worst-case scenario" is $H=\bigcup_{j=1}^nU_{x_j}$. Then $H$ is clopen and $d(K,\partial H)=+\infty$. Even if $X$ is connected, we may have $H=\bigcup_{j=1}^nU_{x_j}$ if $\bigcup_{j=1}^nU_{x_j}=X$. So, do we really need $X$ to be connected? @SeverinSchraven

Comment: You want $H$ to be compact. So you would need to choose $H= \bigcup_{j=1}^n \overline{U}_{x_j}$. I don't understand, how you get that this must be clopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) The argument in the proof is in fact wrong. A counterexample would be $X=[0,2], K=[0,1]$: if I choose the covering $K=[0,1]\subseteq [0,1)\cup (0.5,2]$, then $X=[0,2]$ coincides with the union of the closure of the covering sets.
We need to do some extra work here. Choose $x\in X\setminus K$ (possible as $K\subsetneq X$). Let $C:=d(K, \{ x\})>0$, define $U:= \{ y\in X: d(K,\{ y\}) <C \}$. Then $x\notin U$, $K\subseteq U$ and $U$ is open. Set $\tilde{U}_x:=U_x\cap U$, then

$$ K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n \tilde{U}_{x_i} \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{ \tilde{U}_{x_i}} \subsetneq X.$$

If 
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^n \tilde{U}_{x_i} = V = \bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{ \tilde{U}_{x_i}}$$
then $V$ is clopen and non-empty, thus all of $X$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.